# What should be the best approach/practise when creating Rest Template beans for multiple upstream calls from a microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, optimization, microservices, resttemplate

Currently from our Spring based microservice, we make multiple calls to various other microservices. I wanted to understand what is the best practise of using the rest template bean, should we create a separate rest template bean for each upstream microservice ? Or should we just use a common rest template for all of them ?

Could we gain advantages like isolation when using different rest template for each microservice ? meaning if 1 service is latent, it does not impact other services.

Currently we are using same rest template for all the services.

Comment: I have never had the need to create multiple instances of RestTemplate as the upstream services usually have comparable response times and configurations. However, if you need separate configurations, creating additional rest templates for the odd services seems like a clean solution. I would evaluate this case-by-case but default to creating only one single RestTemplate.

Comment: @ODDminus1 Are you aware if there could be any downside of creating more rest template beans ?

Comment: Other than adding more objects to the memory of the app and diverging slightly from the singleton-pattern, there shouldn't really be any downsides. The memory-part is probably negligible. The main reason I'd default to a single RestTemplate is only for code simplicity, avoiding issues related to mixing up beans of same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a small experiment project by sharing the rest template between two different microservice calls and made one of them latent. It did not impact the performance of another microservice call.

I ended up creating a separate connection pool for each upstream call to make sure there are always enough number of connections for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to configure a separate `RestTemplate` for each service to configure timeouts, error handlers, and interceptors separately. Of course, you can inherit from a general parent and override what is needed.

Also, consider using [Spring Cloud Feign Client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) which allows defining service-specific and default configurations in an easy way.

Comment: Hey Nikolas, Thanks for your answer.

I understand this would be a much cleaner approach, and even I am personally inclined towards doing this. But do you feel it will help me with any additional benefits if the configuration for most of the rest templates are same ? 

Also do you think there could be any downside of this approach,  like multiple rest templates can cause in overall increase in number of connections maybe ?

Our service runs on a very high scale, hence we need to be cautious for minor things as well.

Comment: I am not aware of any disadvantage aside from increased configuration complexity. The `RestTemplate` itself is not responsible for connections and does not use pooling by default. It is useful to configure various `RestTemplate` implementations for custom interceptors and error handlers specific to each service. What matters is the underlying `HttpClient` that defines connection pooling - take a look at `CloseableHttpClient` and `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.